# Calculate function with all values in range?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, math, simulation

I am trying to make a mathematical simulation to find when a condition is met. My approach was to define the conditions and make a while loop that increases the values of x and y. See the code below:

```
# Initialize the variables.

x1list = []
y1list = []
x2list = []
y2list = []

x = 0
y = 0
i = 0

while i < 10:

  # Update data.
  i += 1
  x += .1
  y += .1

  func1 = x + y - 1
  func2 = x * y

  cond1 = func1 < func2 < 1

  if cond1:
    x1list.append(x)
    y1list.append(y)
```

The problem with this code is that it only calculates the condition when x and y increase at the same rate. Sure, I could change the rates, but that would not really solve the problem.

What I want to do is to calculate the condition in a range, say x(-10,10) and y(-10,10). I was thinking about making an array with all x values and another one with all y values, but, then, I don't know how to calculate the condition with all those values.

Another idea that I had was to take a single value of x and test it with all y values, then increase x and test again and again.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: 2D 'simulation' grid**

> I was thinking about making an array with all x values and another one with all y values, but, then, I don't know how to calculate the condition with all those values.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)

# Create 2D simulation meshes for x and y.
# You can read the API entry for meshgrid to learn about options for index 
# ordering, mesh sparsity, and memory copying
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

func1 = X + Y - 1
func2 = X * Y
cond = np.logical_and(func1 < func2, func2 < 1.0) # intrinsic `and` does not work here

# now cond can be used as a 'mask' for any masked-array operations on X and Y
# including for numpy boolean indexing:
print('(X, Y) pairs')
for xy_pair in zip(X[cond], Y[cond]):
    print xy_pair
```

**Method 2: nested loops**

> Another idea that I had was to take a single value of x and test it with all y values, then increase x and test again and again.

```
import numpy as np  # no slower or memory-intensive than `from numpy import arange`

X = []
Y = []
for y in np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1):
    for x in np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1):
        if (x+y-1 < x*y) and (x*y < 1.0):
            X.append(x)
            Y.append(y)

print('(X, Y) pairs')
for xy_pair in zip(X, Y):
    print xy_pair
```

**Which method to choose?**

> How should I approach this problem?

That depends entirely on what you want to do with `(x, y)` pairs that evaluate to `True`. If you edit your question with a bit more guidance, it might become obvious which is the more straightforward solution for your use case.

For instance, **Method 1** provides 2D arrays for plotting the solution space while **Method 2** provides compact python `list`s for databasing.

**Warning: conditional operators**

It also must be pointed out that mathematical expressions with multiple conditional operators do not make sense in Python. This line:

> `cond1 = func1 < func2 < 1`

if evaluated using standard order of operations as `cond1 = (func1 < func2) < 1` would have an intermediate evaluation of `cond1 = (True/False) < 1`, which would implicitly recast `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`, but would not correctly evaluate the mathematical expression `func1 < func2 < 1`.

**EDIT:**

@(Eric Duminil)'s answers provide alternative concepts for solving the underlying mathematical problem, the two methods above assumed your problem needed to be solved numerically on a discrete mesh, and that having those discrete solution points was necessary for whatever code followed.

@Uriel's answer may appear to work, but see my note on conditional operators for why that can be misleading.

Also, I originally typed `and` to combine the 2D conditional statements, but this is incorrect and results in an error. Use `np.logical_and` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem, you don't want to iterate blindly.

First, you can look for obvious solutions : `x = 0` and `y = 0` is one.

You can use [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to try to find general solutions. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%2B%20y%20-%201%20%3C%20x%20*%20y%20%3C%201) is also a great tool for these tasks, and finds this region:

[image]

If those tools cannot find any algebraic solution, you can use [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) to find some numerical results:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def f(x):
    return (x[0] + x[1] - 1)**2 + (x[0] *  x[1])**2

minimize(f, [0,0])
```

It outputs:

```
   status: 0
  success: True
     njev: 6
     nfev: 24
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.59518944, -0.40481056],
       [-0.40481056,  0.59518944]])
      fun: 0.050945906253583216
        x: array([ 0.4533971,  0.4533971])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
      jac: array([ -2.88896263e-06,  -2.88896263e-06])
```

It's a bit of an overkill for this example, but it shows promising results for more complex functions.